# Authenticating Firebase Database with Google API via Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, google-oauth, google-drive-realtime-api

here's the task I have and the resources I'm following to try to get it done.

Ultimately what I want is for users to be able to take pictures with my app (made with Ionic) and then those pictures get sorted and end up on the company's Google Team Drive.

What I originally started with was uploading the images to Firebase Storage, and then I was told they must be accessible to Team Drive.

Some of the people taking pictures aren't part of the company's G Suite, so I was thinking it would be easier to just have the database itself authenticate with the Team Drive and upload from there.

Here is an example from github that shows the same thing I want, except it uploads from Firebase Database to Google Sheets:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-sync

My plan was to follow this guide exactly to get it working, and then figure out how I can change it for Storage -> Team Drive.

However in following the instructions in the readme (they're pretty old) I've come across an error and now I'm stuck.

For Step #7 in that link where it says to run `$ firebase functions:config:set googleapi.client_id="<id>"` and the rest of the command, I get in terminal:

`Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission`

What should be the steps I'm looking at to get this working? I am also unsure if my current implementation makes sense anymore. It wouldn't be a big deal to make everyone using the app sign-in with a Google account so that they can be a member of the Team Drive and just upload directly from the app to Drive. Would that still include the sort of safety behaviour like if the connection drops the file upload will resume independently?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my first question is to install `googleapis` and `google-auth-library`. Run the command in the actual `/functions/` directory of the sample.

There were a few other errors created by old code, but they aren't in the scope of this question and I raised them in the github Issues sections.